# How Log jar file in log from where Log statement is printed

Tags: java, logging, log4j

How to Log the jar file location in log file.
Say I am printing some message from LogTest.java which is in myLog.jar , is there any way to print in log file as below.

`INFO  2013-10-30 15:58:07,227 [log] (LogTest.java:235:myLog.jar) - Some Log Message`

Various jar in a legacy project contain similar kind of log message with the same class name,
It is taking time to investigate any issue. 
Is there any way to handle this please give your suggestion.

Comment: Will adding the package name to the log clarify it? Or do multiple jars contains the same packages?

Comment: Package name and class name (%C.%F) I have already tried but i want to print jar file from where the log is gettting printed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no an option to include the source file with the standar `org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout`. However, you can create your own layout to include it the source. The following may be of use.

```
public class MyLayout extends org.apache.log4j.Layout {
    public void activateOptions() {
        // None action
    }
    public String format(LoggingEvent event) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(event.getLevel());
        sb.append(" (");
        sb.append(event.getLoggerName());
        sb.append(":");
        sb.append(event.getLocationInformation().getLineNumber());
        sb.append(":");
        sb.append(getSource(event.getLoggerName()));
        sb.append(") - ");
        sb.append(event.getMessage());
        sb.append(LINE_SEP);
        return sb.toString();
    }
    public boolean ignoresThrowable() {
        return true;
    }
    public static String getSource(String className) {
        try {
            ClassLoader loader = MyLayout.class.getClassLoader();
            String name = className.replace('.', '/').concat(".class");
            URL url = loader.getResource(name);
            return url.getPath();   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am able to log the statements with the format but it is printing the log location from MyLayout.java not from where i am logging the statement. Say I am printing log at line number 6 at Test.java still I am getting the Logger printed as INFO (smsg.common.util.logger.MyLayout:227:/C:/Users/Myusr/workspace1/my-eclipse-prj/target/classes/smsg/common/util/logger/MyLayout.class) - Helllo rather it should print Test.java and line number.